# How to add a suffix/prefix to a pandas.DataFrame().index?

Tags: python, pandas

I wonder is there a method similar to `add_suffix` that adds a suffix to the index of a dataframe? My current workaround looks like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]}, index=[1, 2, 3])

df = df.T.add_suffix('_x').T

# or 
df.index = df.index.astype(str)+'_x'
```

Unfortunately, the `axis` keyword is not supported by `add_suffix`.

Comment: Don't let the downvotes discourage you from asking more questions like this.  You present an easy way to create your dataframe, a solution that works, but you'd like to improve, and asked a clear question, better than most questions on SO.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### [`pandas.DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)

pass a callable that gets applied to each index value

```
df.rename('{}_x'.format)

     x
1_x  1
2_x  2
3_x  3
```

---

### `set_index`

```
df.set_index(df.index.astype(str) + '_x')

     x
1_x  1
2_x  2
3_x  3
```

Comment: The rename function is great!